# Pandas - Can't change datatype of dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Downloading some data from here:
http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html

Then

```
listings = pd.read_csv('listings.csv')
```

Trying to change types

```
listings.bathrooms = listings.bathrooms.astype('int64',errors='ignore')
listings.bedrooms = listings.bedrooms.astype('int64',errors='ignore')
listings.beds = listings.beds.astype('int64',errors='ignore')
listings.price = listings.price.replace('[\$,]','',regex=True).astype('float')
listings.price = listings.price.astype('int64',errors='ignore')
```

Tried some other combinations but at the end pops error or just doesn't change datatype.

EDIT: corrected some typos

Comment: Look at the column names of your CSV file. Price is present, but the others are not. You can't change the type if it isn't defined. What you've got for price works by the way, because its defined/exists

Answer (score 0):

The apostrophes in the last line is not in the correct place and the last one is not the correct type: you need ' instead of ` (maybe it was accidentaly added because of the code block).

So for me it works like this:

```
listings.price.astype('int64', errors='ignore')
```

But if you would like to reassign it to the original variable then you need the same structure as you used in the previous lines:

```
listings.price = listings.price.astype('int64', errors='ignore')
```

Comment: Sorry actually typos. First yes I missed the ' and secondly to reassign. That code is not working in my comp. Quite strange..

Comment: I could change the data to 'Int64' not 'int64'. Don't know what difference it is but standard datatype should be 'int64'. Still the .astype('int64',...) does not pop error but when you cast .dtypes it shows data type has not changed

Comment: Also listings['bathrooms'] for example still continues behaving as float with values (1.5, 2.5, ...) Any idea why?